# WebDAV in Windows 7 showing incorrect disk size

Tags: windows-7, webdav

I'm currently using Box.Com as a WebDAV disk. But Windows 7 shows incorrect size - apparently the same as the system drive.

Is this can possibly be fixed? If not - what's solution for connecting WebDAV as a disk can also be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't get disk size with WebDAV.

From Microsoft's KB article 2386902: [WebDav mapped drive reports incorrect drive capacity](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2386902):

> Research on WebDAV protocol RFCs and verification from Microsoft's product team confirmed WebDAV protocol doesn’t support querying server’s disk capacity. With this constrain of WebDAV protocol, Windows client sets WebDAV mapping drive’s capacity the same as its System Drive.

Comment: So, that's a problem of WebDAV itself? Thanks!